# Writing a list value horizontally using csv.DictWriter

Tags: python, csv

I have a dict that I want to write to a CSV file. However, some of the keys in the dict have a list of values, I want to write each element of the list horizontally in a seperate cell.

```
data = {"Age": 28, "Name": "Some Name", "Aliases": ["alias1", "alias2"]}
fieldnames = ['Age', 'Name', 'Aliases']

with open(f, 'a') as o:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(o, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Aliases get written as an array in a single cell which is expected. I converted list to a comma separated string `data["Aliases"] = ', '.join(data['Aliases'])` but this comma separated string is also getting written to the same cell.

Any ideas on how each element of the list can be written to a seperate cell.

Comment: When you join the list, you are creating a single string argument that is written to a single cell.  Rather than using `DictWriter`, you may want to read each dictionary value and write it if it isn't a list, then handle the list items when you find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### CSV files have delimiters, not cells

It's a small but important point. What you mean by "cell" is presumably what you see when you open the CSV file in Excel. Comma delimiters and quotation marks to separate delimiters *within* a field have special meaning with programs which read CSV files.

`csv.DictWriter` is good for structured data, i.e. one value for each field per row. Your data is inherently unstructured. If you want each row to have an arbitrary length you can achieve this via `csv.writer`:

```
import csv

data = {"Age": 28, "Name": "Some Name", "Aliases": ["alias1", "alias2"]}
fieldnames = ['Age', 'Name', 'Aliases']

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    writer.writerow([data['Age'], data['Name'], *data['Aliases']])
```

Result `file.csv`:

```
Age,Name,Aliases
28,Some Name,alias1,alias2
```